# I want to give a score based on the result of the game, but an error occurs

Tags: r, scoring

I have a problem in scoring game
The game is Russian roulette
I want to replicate the game 10 times and give a point to the survivors

```
game <- replicate(10, shot())
data.frame(table(game))
```

and I got this game result

```
              game Freq
1 player1 game end    4
2 player3 game end    2
3 player4 game end    1
4 player6 game end    3
```

I want to know how I can convert game results into scores like this 
by giving one point to the survivors

```
1 player1 point 6
2 player2 point 10
3 player3 point 8
4 player4 point 9
5 player5 point 10
6 player6 point 7
```

but I don't get any clue about it
I desperately need some help

I add my code

```
shot <- function()
{
  if(sample(c(1,-1),1,prob=c(1/6,5/6)) == T) 
  {
    print("player1 game end") #if p1 get true at 1st round it end
  }
  else if(shot <- sample(c(1,-1),1,prob=c(1/5,4/5)) == T) 
  {
    print("player2 game end") #if p2 get true at 2nd round it end
  }
  else if(shot <- sample(c(1,-1),1,prob=c(1/4,3/4)) == T) 
  {
    print("player3 game end") #if p3 get true at 3rd round it end
  }
  else if(shot <- sample(c(1,-1),1,prob=c(1/3,2/3)) == T) 
  {
    print("player4 game end") #if p4 get true at 4th round it end
  }
  else if(shot <- sample(c(1,-1),1,prob=c(1/2,1/2)) == T) 
  {
    print("player5 game end") #if p5 get true at 5th round it end
  }else if(shot <- sample(c(1,-1),1,prob=c(1,0)) == T) 
  {
    print("player6 game end") #if p6 get true at 5th round it end
  }
}
shot()
```

My game start with this code
How can I combine with scoring code

```
game
player <- sample(1:6, size = 6, replace = FALSE) 
player

names(player)[player==1] <- "p1"  
names(player)[player==2] <- "p2" 
names(player)[player==3] <- "p3" 
names(player)[player==4] <- "p4" 
names(player)[player==5] <- "p5"
```

Comment: How's your code look like. Post your code!!!

Comment: I post my main code!! The code works well but I don't have any idea how I can convert result to score

Comment: I believe what @KrishnaKuntala was referring to was that your code is *not* [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Since we don't know what `shot()` does there's nothing here for us to work with nor can we reproduce your "game result". Please take a look at the post I link to and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @MauritsEvers The code is there and reproducible, the question is fine as it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what we can do. First, we create a `players` `data.frame`, which we'll use to join up to the games result `data.frame`. Then we calculate `score`, which appears to be `10 - Freq`:

```
# generate games
set.seed(1) # reproducible
games <- replicate(10, shot())
# make players data
players <- data.frame(player = paste0("player", 1:6))
# make games data
games_table <- data.frame(table(games))
games_table$player <- gsub(" game end", "", games_table$games) # player ID
# merge data
players <- merge(players, games_table, all.x = TRUE)
# create score
players$score <- 10 - ifelse(is.na(players$Freq), 0, players$Freq)

#    player            games Freq score
# 1 player1 player1 game end    2     8
# 2 player2 player2 game end    2     8
# 3 player3 player3 game end    1     9
# 4 player4 player4 game end    2     8
# 5 player5             <NA>   NA    10
# 6 player6 player6 game end    3     7
```

Comment: I have a problem while combing your answer and my code. I add it on my question can I get more help?

Comment: I would suggest making the names __consistent__ across your `shot` function and your data (either use `player1`, player2`,... in both or `p1`, `p2` in both).